# Maximal Ideals of Different Heights

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to see how it is possible for rings to have maximal ideals of different heights. For this,
I need to see *various* cases of such rings. I can construct one case by localization using methods outlined in [this math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110533/can-a-non-local-ring-have-only-two-prime-ideals/2110620#2110620).

Now I want to construct other cases with the following property:
The ring $R$ has infinitely many maximal ideals, one with height $3$ and one with height $2$. Any other case of rings with  maximal ideals of different heights are welcomed.

Comment: Throughout all of this, are you implicitly thinking "integral domain"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a ring $R_1$ which has a maximal ideal  of height 2, a ring $R_2$ with a maximal ideal of height 3, and form $R=R_1\times R_2\times \mathbb Z$.

That would suit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. multiply by Z is a very good idea.