# Maximal Ideals of Different Heights in a domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In continue of this question: [Maximal Ideals of Different Heights](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336328/maximal-ideals-of-different-heights) ; and regarding  @rschwieb 's comment,

Now I want to construct other cases with the following property:
1- The ring $R$ is a *domain* and has some maximal ideals, one with height $3$ and one with height $2$.
2- The ring $R$ is a *domain* and has infinitely many maximal ideals, one with height $3$ and one with height $2$. (I dont want use localizing in 2 primes of different heights).

---

Any other case of *domains* with  maximal ideals of different heights are welcomed.

Comment: If there is a finite map from a regular domain to $R$ (eg $R$ is a finite type algebra over a field), than by “going-up/going-down” it should be impossible.

Comment: I was merely claiming that such rings couldn’t be of finite type over a field. Meaning that counterexamples, while they certainly exist, will be more complicated.

Comment: oh, thank you... maybe beyond my level, yes? still, answers welcomed, and are helpful for me or others .--- Also, your comment is helpful

Comment: Something that might work: we can (rather easily) find a finite-type $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra $A$ which is *connected but not integral* and that satisfies similar conditions (say, has one maximal ideal of height $1$ and one of height $2$ – consider the reunion of the plane $z=0$ and the line $x=y=0$). Perhaps $A$ can be lifted to an integral $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra $R$, raising by $1$ the height of the corresponding maximal ideals…

Comment: can u please post the answer with some details?

Comment: I wish I could, but that’s a sketch of an argument in the comments for a reason. Namely, I don’t know how to do the lifting from $R$ to $A$ (the crux of the argument). Why don’t you try figuring it out?

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a valuation domain of dimension $2$ and assume $m=tR$ for its maximal ideal and $p R_p=s R_p$ for the other non-zero prime ideal. Consider the polynomial ring $R[X]$. Its Krull dimension is $3$: according to Theorem 2 in

M. Nagata, *Finitely generated rings over a valuation ring*, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 5-2 (1966), 163-169

every maximal saturated chain

$0\subset p_1\subset\ldots\subset p_\ell$

of prime ideals in $R[X]$ has a length equal to

$\ell=\mathrm{height}(p_\ell\cap R)+1-\mathrm{trdeg}(R[X]/p_\ell|R/(p_\ell\cap R))$.

The right-hand side becomes maximal, if one chooses $p_\ell$ such that for the transcendence degree $\mathrm{trdeg}(R[X]/p_\ell|R/(p_\ell\cap R))=0$ holds and $p_\ell\cap R$ is maximal. An example of a maximal saturated chain of prime ideals is $0\subset p[X]\subset m[X]\subset m[X]+XR[X]$.

The ideal $(tX-1)R[X]$ is a prime ideal of height $1$, since $(tX-1)K[X]$ is a prime ideal, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$.

We have $R[X]/(tX-1)R[X]=R[\frac{1}{t}]=R_p$: the kernel of the evaluation homomorphisms $R[X]\rightarrow R[\frac{1}{t}]$ contains $(tX-1)R[X]$. Now let $f\in R[X]$ be a polynomial with $f(\frac{1}{t})=0$. We may assume that one of its coefficients is a unit of $R$. In $K[X]$ we have the factorization $f=q(tX-1)$. Gauss's lemma then yields $q\in R[X]$.
$R[\frac{1}{t}]$ is a proper overring of $R$, hence it is either equal to $R_p$ or to $K$. However $\frac{1}{s}\not\in R[\frac{1}{t}]$: if it were, we had a relation

$
\frac{1}{s}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nr_k\frac{1}{t^k}, r_k\in R.
$

Multiplikation by $s$ yields

$
1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nr_k\frac{s}{t^k},
$

which is a contradiction, because $\frac{s}{t^k}\in m$ for all $k$.

The valuation domain $R_p$ has dimension $1$, so that we obtain a maximal chain of primes $0\subset (tX-1)\subset q$, where $q/(tX-1)R[X]=pR_p$.

According to Corollary 3.4 of

Bouvier, Dobbs, Fontana, *Universally catenarian integral domains*, Advances in Mathematics 72,

$R[X]$ is catenarian, hence $q$ has height $2$. Actually Theorem 1 of

Bouvier, Dobbs, Fontana, *TWO SUFFICIENT CONDITIONS FOR UNIVERSAL CATENARITY*, COMMUNICATIONS IN ALGEBRA, 15(4), 861-872  (1987)

is the more adequate reference. The first one however is available online.

Answer (score 2):

### Partial answer:

The paper *Hilbert integral domains with maximal ideals of preassigned height* by William Heinzer has an example, but it is not simple.
It is available at "Journal of Algebra, Volume 29, Issue 2, May 1974, Pages 229-231".
Also, you can find another example as reference 5 of the above paper.